# Deep update of Mongo DB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have the following document structure in Mongo DB 3.0 document:

```
{
    id: "ID",
    name: "NAME",
    items:[
        {
            id:"100",
            name:"Item Name",
            fields:[
                {a:"field 1", b:44},
                {a:"field 2", b:56},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update "field 2" to value of 72, so that the result will be as follow:

```
{
    id: "ID",
    name: "NAME",
    items:[
        {
            id:"100",
            name:"Item Name",
            fields:[
                {a:"field 1", b:44},
                {a:"field 2", b:72},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you stumbled upon a very annoying limitation of MongoDB.

You can update individual array entries with [the $ placeholder](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). But unfortunately you can only have one of these in a field-name. That means arrays-within-arrays can not be updated with a single query.

A possible workaround is to use a `find` to request a copy of the whole `items.$.fields` array, edit it on the application layer, and then do an update which replaces the whole array.

There is [an open ticket on the official bugtracker about this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) which has "major" priority. But the ticket exists since 2010, so I wouldn't hold me breath.

Comment: I am ok with a bit more work, it is not a requirement to have a single query, can you help me with complete answer?

Comment: @vladtax For that you would need to tell me which programming language your application is written in and hope that it's a language I am at least a bit familiar with.